# ¿Cómo mostrar un solo índice de un arreglo con otros datos?

Tags: javascript, json

Buen día amigos,

tengo el siguiente arreglo de objetos

```
1: {fechas: "24-10", registros: "3"}
2: {fechas: "24-10", registros: "9"}
3: {fechas: "24-10", registros: "5"}
4: {fechas: "25-10", registros: "2"}
5: {fechas: "25-10", registros: "11"}
```

¿Hay alguna manera de poner la fecha y que sume los registros?
Es decir de la siguiente manera

```
1: {fechas: "24-10", registros: "17"}
4: {fechas: "25-10", registros: "13"}
```

o sea setear el areglo de objetos para que me traiga registros por fecha

Comment: los datos los obtienes desde una consulta sql ? si es asi podrias colocar el codigo de dicha consulta..!!

Comment: @Tegito123 Sí es de una consulta sql, ahí la puedes ver

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array = [
  {fechas: "24-10", registros: "3"},
  {fechas: "24-10", registros: "9"},
  {fechas: "24-10", registros: "5"},
  {fechas: "25-10", registros: "2"},
  {fechas: "25-10", registros: "11"}
];

var sum = array.reduce((acc, current) => {
    if (acc[current.fechas] == null) {
      acc[current.fechas] = 0;
    }
    
    acc[current.fechas] += (+current.registros || 0);
    
    return acc;
}, { });

// Hasta aquí tienes un objeto sum con la forma:
// { '24-10': 17, '25-10': 13 }
// Si lo quieres convertir a un array de objetos:    

var result = Object
  .keys(sum)
  .map(key => ({ 'fechas': key, 'registros': sum[key] }));

console.log(result);
```

---

O si prefieres desde SQL, que no necesitarías tanta manipulación, cambia COUNT por SUM y remover los campos  `lastapp, lastdata` y `disposition`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(calldate,'%d-%c') AS fecha , SUM(calldate) AS registros
FROM cdr 
WHERE ...
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(calldate,'%d-%c')
ORDER BY fecha ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

en este caso te resulta mas facil realizarlo por consulta a tu BD: algo asi, suponiendo la siguiente estructura:

[image: posible estructura]

la consulta seria algo asi:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%d-%c') AS fecha,
    sum(cdr.registros) as total_registros,
    cdr.lastapp
FROM 
    cdr
    GROUP BY fecha
```

y tu resultado seria:

[image: resultado]

Como notaras uso la funcion de sum, como su nombre lo indica permite sumar el campo deseado, a su vez realizo un group by fecha que me permite agrupar por fechas iguales y sumar los campos indicados en este caso registro, es un inicio alli debes adaptar a tus ncesidades espero haberte ayudado !!

[Documentacion Sum](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_sum.asp)